# Problem to plot data with dates using an external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

Using logs to make statistics, I have a large number of data which contains two columns, like this (dd-mm-aaaa hh-mm float)

```
27-04-2018 04:43    7.78269552
27-04-2018 04:44    7.901522832
27-04-2018 04:45    7.754261587
27-04-2018 04:46    7.823737353
27-04-2018 04:47    7.799246215
27-04-2018 04:48    7.739765084
27-04-2018 04:49    7.776174494
27-04-2018 04:50    7.71269577
27-04-2018 04:51    7.682809896
27-04-2018 04:52    7.66061104
27-04-2018 04:53    7.727415335
27-04-2018 04:54    7.679670753
27-04-2018 04:55    7.677914655
```

By trying to plot those datas, I've written this :

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={\shorthandoff{:;!?};}}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
xticklabel=\day. \hour:\minute
]
\addplot table [mark=none] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know that there are some packages or infos that may not be necessary on that code, but it's just a sample of my document, that I've cut. I can still separate my two columns with a coma, but still i get that message :

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '04:44' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ':44'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Hope my problem is clear enough. I've already looked on many other questions which doesn't answer it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your columns are whitespace separated you have, as far as `pgfplots` is concerned, *three* columns in the data file, not two. If there is a tab between the two columns, you can try using

```
\addplot[mark=none] table[col sep=tab]  {data.txt};
```

Alternatively, use for example a comma instead, i.e.

```
27-04-2018 04:43,    7.78269552
```

and then use `col sep=comma` to inform `pgfplots` of the column separator:

```
\addplot[mark=none] table[col sep=comma]  {data.txt};
```

(Your `[mark=none]` was in the wrong place, it is an option that concerns the plotting, not the table reading.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz which loads pgf

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={\shorthandoff{:;!?};}}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


%%%%%%%% just for example %%%%%%%%%%%
% filecontents makes the example self-contained
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
27-04-2018 04:43,    7.78269552
27-04-2018 04:44,    7.901522832
27-04-2018 04:45,    7.754261587
27-04-2018 04:46,    7.823737353
27-04-2018 04:47,    7.799246215
27-04-2018 04:48,    7.739765084
27-04-2018 04:49,    7.776174494
27-04-2018 04:50,    7.71269577
27-04-2018 04:51,    7.682809896
27-04-2018 04:52,    7.66061104
27-04-2018 04:53,    7.727415335
27-04-2018 04:54,    7.679670753
27-04-2018 04:55,    7.677914655
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%---------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
xticklabel=\day. \hour:\minute,
xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east} % one option for making the ticklabels readable
]
\addplot[mark=none] table[col sep=comma]  {mydata.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The data looks like it is tab delimited. Wouldn't it be better to say `col sep=tab`? so he don't has to change the datafile

Comment: @sporc If that's the case, yes, that didn't even occur to me. (I never use tabs for anything.) The part of the file shown in the question has spaces though.

Comment: I think the spaces come from a tab delimiter when copying the file contents. 4 spaces = 1 tab

Comment: @sporc Quite possibly, I don't know. Feel free to add answer yourself, if you don't want me to add it to mine.

Comment: I still got a problem of with unit :
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Your answer is good, but maybe you can add that it is also possible with `col sep = tab` if its tab delimited ;)

Comment: @HugoVernier-Lambert Impossible to say where that may come without more info.  Exactly what code gives you that error?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've just copied yours to try it, and it gives this error :(

Comment: ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
7
l.24 ...rk=none] table[col sep=comma] {data.txt};
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Comment: @HugoVernier-Lambert Can you try the code that is in my answer now (just updated)? If that throws an error (it works fine here), can you add the complete `.log` file to your question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works fine here too, should i send you the `.log` of the old one ?

Comment: @HugoVernier-Lambert Start by comparing the two `.tex` files and the data files (`mydata.dat` and your `data.txt`), see if you can find any differences.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok, because the data i gave you was only a sample of the data. I've tried with less data, and it works fine, so what should i do to plot a bigger file of data ? And is this normal that the written day is 08 and not 27 ?

Comment: @HugoVernier-Lambert I don't know why a larger data file would fail with an error like that. Would it be possible to show the entire file somewhere, e.g. pastebin.com? Sorry, I didn't even notice that the date was wrong. The date format has to be `yyyy-mm-dd`, then it's correct.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You can find the entire file on https://pastebin.com/ifSn2n1v

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok for the date format

Comment: @HugoVernier-Lambert Works fine here with the complete file as well. One thing you want to remove though is `xtick=data`, as that gives you a tick for every line in the file, and 919 ticks isn't really helpful.

Comment: I just tried it too and works too with the right date format.